# how to upload a audio file using HTTP POST from blackberry 5.0?

Tags: audio, blackberry, http-post, audio-recording

i need to upload a audio file stored in phone memory using http post. what steps required for it. any helps will be appreciated.

i doing the client side progrmming.

```
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    ConnectionFactory connFact = new ConnectionFactory();
    ConnectionDescriptor connDesc;
    connDesc = connFact.getConnection(url);
    if (connDesc != null)
    {
        HttpConnection httpConn;
        httpConn = (HttpConnection)connDesc.getConnection();
        httpConn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
        URLEncodedPostData encPostData = new URLEncodedPostData("UTF-8", false);
```

//here i want to append the audio data from phone memmory . how it will be done?

thanks

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow. What is your question? Are you concerned with the client (blackberry) programming or with the server (site) programming? What have you tried so far? what is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an example of using the HTTP POST protocol in the API documentation for HttpConnection. You will, as PA suggests, have to provide an HTTP server to accept the conection and do something with the data.